# While loop in C - read untiL sentinel variations

Tags: c, while-loop

I am learning C and I would like to know if there is any difference or one way is better than the other between these two while loop variations. Should I use one instead of the other? Maybe one of those variations is wrong?

```
 while(car_num<=car_limit)
    {
     car_num = ceil(car_num*(1+rate));
     year++;
    }
```

OR

```
while(TRUE)  { if(car_num>car_limit)
                break;
     car_num = ceil(car_num*(1+rate));
     year++; }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is better because easier to understand. In general, avoid while(true).